# My PRNG use is safe; how do I tell SonarQube not to yell at me

Tags: sonarqube

I am using java.util.Random to append random numbers to the names of some objects in a testing environment.  I do these random values will never be used in any cryptography contexts.  The instruction from SonarQube is "Make sure that using this pseudorandom number generator is safe here."  I have, indeed, "made sure".  Thank you, SonarQube, for your diligence.

Now what?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2245") // this PRNG usage is safe
private static final Random random = new Random();
```

Props to SonarQube for hooking into the SuppressWarnings annotation, slops for the name of the identifier

Answer (score 0):

Using import *java.security.SecureRandom* instead of java.util.Random, worked for me =)

```
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    int random5DigitNumber = secureRandom.nextInt(100000);
```